# How to pronounce G°?

Tags: terminology

To denote standard state like enthalpy of formation in standard state, or change in Gibbs free energy in standard state, we use a degree-like symbol above the $G$ as in $\Delta G^0$. How should I refer to this superscript in spoken language?

Comment: That's not a degree at all, but a _zero_.

Comment: Then how should i pronounce it ? "g zero" ?

Comment: What about G nought (or G null or G sub zero) and G prime?

Comment: I heard people pronounce like that "G nought" and "G prime" . But I am not sure these are the right ones.

Comment: There is no authority-on-high for English language usage. I suspect that "G nought" and "G prime" were understood (or are perfectly understandable) by one and all, so are quite OK to use. Nobody will issue you a language ticket...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

G-zero and G-prime.

G-zero has also in my presence been referred to as "G-ought", "G-nought", "standard-G" or "G at standard state". I am particular towards "G-zero" myself. (Mostly because of a witty limerick I heard during my studies. Zero rhymes with hero.)